# How to auto-reload tabs in Chrome if there was no internet connection?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome produces the following screen if a tab is opened while there was no internet connection:

[image]

Is it possible for Chrome to auto-reload all tabs that couldn't be opened previously because there was no internet connection as soon as there is again a connection available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, yes, it should. Chrome does that automatically on my laptop (Windows 10 64-bit) when I reconnect to a WiFi access point.

Could you try out if that works like that on your end as well? Otherwise, I might have to do some digging in about:flags to figure out if it's some obscure setting I've changed myself.

**Edit 2016-06-23: I think I found it!**
@orschiro Do a CTRL+F search on the chrome://flags/ page for "reload". The first two results should do what you want. ("Enable offline auto reload" and "Enable offline auto reload, visible only")

Comment: Yes, this works "automatically" for me too, although I don't think it does it for "all tabs" in one go (if that is what the OP wants). If the tab is left open, or as soon as the user navigates back to that tab, it appears to reload (if there was previously a connection problem) - this works quite well for me. (Personally, I wouldn't want it to load "all tabs" in the background - if that is the intention).

Comment: Oh, you're actually completely right, @w3dk. Very observant! :-)

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm on Ubuntu Linux 16.04. Maybe it's indeed a flag that I need to enable first but which one could it be?

Comment: The flags "Enable offline auto reload" and "Enable offline auto reload, visible only" no longer exists (Chrome 93.0.4577.82). Now what? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Chrome URL --> **chrome://flags/**

Offline Auto-Reload Mode Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android
Pages that fail to load while the browser is offline will be auto-reloaded when the browser is online again. **#enable-offline-auto-reload**  [[ENABLE]]

Only Auto-Reload Visible Tabs Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android
Pages that fail to load while the browser is offline will only be auto-reloaded if their tab is visible. **#enable-offline-auto-reload-visible-only** [[DISABLE]]

Comment: The flags "Enable offline auto reload" and "Enable offline auto reload, visible only" no longer exists (Chrome 93.0.4577.82). Now what? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Updated method.It easy to enable this feature, just follow steps
1. **Go to **http://chrome://flags (chrome://flags)
2. **Search for “AutoFetchOnNetError**
3. **You can see result, enable the flag**
4. **Relaunch Chrome.**

Comment: AutoFetchOnNetError is not available in Chrome 93.0.4577.82. Any suggestions?